# CMD glass removal

Tags: command-line

I've installed some theme glass-kind of for CMD. I've looked for tutorials on how to remove it on google, but I can't remember what did I install. There is no program or something running in the background or so.

Anyway to get the old look back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded glass command from yegorius on DeviantART. I've forgot what I've downloaded and began searching over the internet how could I remove the CMD glass thingy. Then I've searched my browsers history for over three hours, and found the link. I've downloaded the uninstaller and ran the uninstall.bat.

here's the link: http://www.deviantart.com/art/Glass-Command-194141707

bam, done.